# Возможно ли снять свою кандидатуру с выборов на этапе голосования?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Если возможно, то как? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: Можно сойти с гонки, получив бан ;)

Comment: Ну если вдруг за тебя проголосовали, а ты снимешься. То куда голос уйдёт...

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev интересный вопрос.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ слишком просто.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev так голосов три, и отдавать не обязательно все насколько я понимаю. Так что тут проблемы быть не должно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну а если я хочу все три отдать... получается что один сгорает

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev голос сгорает вместе с кандидатом :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я прослоупочил... пока выборы не закончились можно же переголосовать)))

Comment: @Suvitruf ты просто очень устал, отдохни немного от компьютера, и через какое-то время всё будет выглядеть в более позитивном виде. Я тоже отдал за тебя голос.

Comment: @Suvitruf, абстрактный интерес  или в самом деле?

Comment: @avp 95% - теоретически, 5% на самом деле)

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev можно. Но ведь надо тогда не пропустить момент изменения кол-ва кандидатов, если он будет возможен.