# На новой странице синонимов меток не переведены строки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, синонимы-меток

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Безобразие. Где этот чертов локализатор!?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: На картинке версия, кстати, снова с ромбовидными добавками. Не забывайте надевать <s>старое платье и выходить в люди</s> сокпупета для некоторых проверок.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ничего такого, что подпадает под PII )

Comment: Модераторы чтоб сами свой хлам переводили :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ участников банить нужно, а теперь ещё переводить самим? (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: Надо было [сниматься с выборов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9214/176217) пока была такая возможность :) Теперь придётся страдать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ поезд ушёл. Теперь придётся иронизировать везде, чтоб сняли ромб (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Подгрузилось уже.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ но не всё переведено https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested https://monosnap.com/file/zmRXXBgdbeQFZ40XYOa20w8cYyGUcs

Comment: Только что перевёл как раз это.

Comment: Что-то осталось ещё не пофикшено?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вроде только в модерке. Это сам вобью позже, раз больше некому)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы все переводы сделал/утвердил предложенные ([MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight) подсуетился тоже). Посмотрим, что получится.

Ждём подкачки и пересборки версии сайта.

Comment: Что-то там столько всяких скрытых строк оказалось: другие страницы, хинты ... может чего-то ушло из-под взгляда. Пишите тогда тут комментами или сразу предлагайте перевод на ru.traducir.win, поправим.

Comment: Завтра ещё посмотрю.

Comment: @Suvitruf правильно. Хватит на сегодня энтузиазма.